# Combine data frames in R unless entry already exists

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, rbind

I have a large data frame A that has sales figures for different items for only a few weeks and doesn't mention the weeks where no sales occurred. I therefore created a second data frame B where I have included all weeks with sales set to 0. I now want to add B to A but not for the weeks where A already mentions a sale. I was hoping to do this via an added combination variable but can't seem to figure out a fast way to do this.

So I have for example

```
A  Week ID Sales Combination           B   Week ID Sales Combination
   1    X  5     1_X                       1    X  0     1_X
   2    X  6     2_X                       2    X  0     2_X
   5    X  5     5_X                       3    X  0     3_X
   6    X  4     6_X                       4    X  0     4_X
   1    Y  2     1_Y                       5    X  0     5_X
   3    Y  2     3_Y                       6    X  0     6_X
   5    Y  2     5_Y                       1    Y  0     1_Y
                                           2    Y  0     2_Y
                                           3    Y  0     3_Y
                                           4    Y  0     4_Y
                                           5    Y  0     5_Y
```

And what I want is this

```
 Week ID Sales Combination
 1    X  5     1_X
 2    X  6     2_X
 3    X  0     3_X
 4    X  0     4_X
 5    X  5     5_X
 6    X  4     6_X
 1    Y  2     1_Y
 2    Y  0     2_Y
 3    Y  2     3_Y
 4    Y  0     4_Y
 5    Y  2     5_Y
```

Hope this makes it more or less clear.

Comment: please make your examples reproducible.

Comment: You probably want to merge, but leave the Sales out of B. As already mentioned, if you include data in a [reproducible format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) it would be easier to help and test possible answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `dfA` be the first data.frame, and `dfB` be the second one, you could do

```
# Get relevant data together
new_df = rbind(dfA, dfB[dfA$Combination != dfB$Combination,])

# Order the data frame
sorting_index = sort(new_df$Combination, index.return=T)
new_df = new_df[sorting.index$ix,]
```

Alternatively, you could set your new data frame as being `dfB` and then use `match` to get the values from `dfA` and put them at the right place.

Answer (score 0):

```
newdataframe <- rbind(A,B,by='week')
newdataframe <- newdataframe[!duplicated(newdataframe$week),]
```

This should solve it